# Is it possible to append another value to existing variable in sass / scss?

Tags: css, sass

I have this defined in an external file of a framework I am using:

```
$font-family-sans-serif: "Helvetica Neue", "Roboto", "Segoe UI", sans-serif !default;
```

I want to prepand my own font (in a different file , e.g, without altering the FW variables file).

```
$font-family-sans-serif: 'MyFont', $font-family-sans-serif;
```

So, is it possible? The above is not working.

```
Error: Undefined variable: "$font-family-sans-serif".
        on line 3 of scss/variables.scss
        on line 3 of scss/variables.scss
>> $font-family-sans-serif: 'MyFont', $font-family-sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's valid SASS as long as these files are compiled together. Are you sure that external file with the variable `$font-family-sans-serif` has been included before you modify the variable?

Here's your example, but concatenated. It works fine:

```
$font-family-sans-serif: "Helvetica Neue", "Roboto", "Segoe UI", sans-serif !default;
$font-family-sans-serif: 'MyFont', $font-family-sans-serif;
```